# Header does not work in typescript Angular

Tags: angular, header

I am working with angular but when i run de app in a ngnix server, the server doesnt identify the header x-nonce.
The API send : 400 error.
i dont know why  the browser doesnt send the x-nonce header to the api service.

i cleaned the chache and the error still.

```
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Authorization': token,
    'x-nonce': uuid(),
    'x-date': fecha.toUTCString()
  }),
  params: new HttpParams()
    .set('company', filter._company)
    .set('user', filter._user)
    .set('skip', skipt)
    .set('limit', limit)
};
```

return this.http.get(this.apiEndpointReports, httpOptions);

Comment: there may be the issue with server/API config (it doesn't accept specific header)

Comment: @Carlos please post your entire Http call code